# If $K≤H≤G$, $[H:K] = n$, and $\{H': H≤H'≤G\}$ finite, does the same hold for $K$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be a group and $K≤H≤G$ be subgroups such that

- $[H:K]=n$
- $[H, G]_{\mathrm{sub}} = \{H' | H≤H'≤G\}$ is finite,

**Question:** Do we necessarily have that there are only finitely many subgroups between $K$ and $G$ as well?

If we use the correspondence between stabilizer supergroups and superblocks, we can note

- In the (transitive) action $G\curvearrowright G/K$, we have that $K=G_{1K}$, the stabilizer of the coset $1E$
- $H$ corresponds to the finite block $G_{H/K}$ consisting of its cosets
- there are only finitely many blocks $ℬ\supseteq G_{H/K}$.

**Question:** Can we already deduce that there are only finitely many blocks $ℬ'\supseteq \{1E\}$?
If not, is there a counterexample?

---

I've tried to see whether I can find a characterization for when $H'_1, H'_2$ both generate the same subgroup when adjoining $H$ in hopes there could be only finitely many such $H'_i$, but I've gotten nowhere.

I apologize if there is a trivial counterexample I overlooked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tarski monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) provide counterexamples. A Tarski monster for prime $p$ is an infinite group whose proper, nontrivial subgroups have order $p$. Such groups are simple.

Let $G$ be a Tarski monster for prime $p$, let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $p$, and let $K=\{e\}$. We have $[H\colon K]=p<\infty$ and the only subgroups $H'$ satisfying $H\leq H'\leq G$ are $H'=H$ and $H'=G$. On the other hand, the conjugates of $H$ provide infinitely many subgroups $H'$ satisfying $K\leq H'\leq G$.